# Marker information representation with leaflet

Tags: leaflet

```
       control = L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
        fitBounds: true,
        layerOptions: {
            style: style,
            pointToLayer: function (data, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(
                    latlng,

                    { style: style }
                );
            }
        }
    });

    control.addTo(map);
```

[the dots appear as in the picture but when you click on it, the information does not come where is my mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc91k.png)

[I want it to appear that belongs to the dots as in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vabW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your question! What do you want? Take a look into: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a popup to the layer:

```
control = L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
        fitBounds: true,
        layerOptions: {
            style: style,
            pointToLayer: function (data, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(
                    latlng,

                    { style: style }
                );
            },
           onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
             //load your data for popup feature.properties.YOUROBJECT
             layer.bindPopup("test String");
           }
        }
    });
```

Please don't for get to check the answer